# Save row as text file, get filename from cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This google script successfully creates a text file for each row but it names each file after the row number, e.g., "row0.txt", "row1.txt". I would like to have each text file named for the cell in ColA in its relevant row.
row1.txt would be saved as White Ribbon - 1999.txt
row2.txt would be saved as Contagion - 2011.txt

I realize the trick is in the last 2 lines, but I'm flumoxed as to how I can get the correct cell contents (A1, A2, A3, etc) as the filename for each row.

here's [my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cDw0gJsOqWBazEakacAGtrjisqQJtAbERNv8y9Ifvpk/edit#gid=1418795302)

And here's the script I'm using (note that I'm saving to *md rather than *txt)

```
function saveRowsToTextfile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:W4");
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Test").next();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
  rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    folder.createFile("row" + index + ".md", row.join("\n"));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include **column A** in your range and use `shift()` before joining the array to remove the first element of each sub-array which is the title.

Your code should look like this:

```
function saveRowsToTextfile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:W4");
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Test").next();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) files.next().setTrashed(true);
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    var title = row[0]; //set first element of array as title
    row.shift(); //remove first element of the array 
    var content = row.join("\n");
    folder.createFile(title + ".md", content);
  }); 
}
```

Output:

[image]

### Reference

- [Array.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Comment: Nikko J, thank you SO much. It works like charm. After using the script for a while I'm wondering... is there a way to have it exclude empty cells from the output? I'm using many if(isblank) rules, and the resulting md files have a bunch of empty space where the exported cells are blank. It's not a big deal, I just thought if there was some simple line I could add to the code to avoid that it would save me a lot of post-export effort.